# Python exceptions in Docker logs marked as stream: stdout

Tags: python, docker

I want parse and handle all errors from docker container, but python exceptions marked as stdout, when I expect stderr.

As example simple **app.py**

```
raise Exception("!")
```

Then I run this file in docker container.
But in **/var/lib/docker/containers/.../...-json.log**:

```
{"log":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-17T23:10:01.58636849Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/var/app.py\", line 1, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-17T23:10:01.586581081Z"}
{"log":"    raise Exception(\"!\")\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-17T23:10:01.586842665Z"}
{"log":"Exception: !\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-17T23:10:01.587373678Z"}
```

Comment: do you find them with `docker logs`?, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#logs

Comment: yes, but I want filter simple output and errors

Comment: I see `$ docker run -d --name foo busybox ls abcd
$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log
$ cat stderr.log
ls: abcd: No such file or directory` from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7440, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a misconception. I thought that the command of docker CLI does not affect the main logs (/var/lib/docker/containers/.../...-json.log)

But in case with:

**docker run -it my_python python /var/app.py**

json.log content:

```
{"log":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:55.842010241Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/var/app.py\", line 1, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:55.842252975Z"}
{"log":"    raise Exception(\"error\")\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:55.842423153Z"}
{"log":"Exception: error\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:55.842754372Z"}
```

But if I run container in background, stream become stderr:

**docker run -d my_python python /var/app.py**

```
{"log":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:18.905673576Z"}
{"log":"  File \"/var/app.py\", line 1, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:18.90575399Z"}
{"log":"    raise Exception(\"error\")\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:18.905802834Z"}
{"log":"Exception: error\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2015-06-18T10:02:18.90616668Z"}
```

I think this behavior implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

docker logs separating stdout from stderr:

```
$ docker run -d --name foo busybox ls abcd
9a432862fb838b422d6b06446bc817d71cef09254059ec1ca92d0742580b81a4
$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log 
$ cat stderr.log 
ls: abcd: No such file or directory
$
```

vs

```
$ docker run -d --name foo busybox ls /
5aff475fe0aa864c22633e7b915f7271e0a009b003371e9cdf2fbf1bae224709
$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log 
bin
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
linuxrc
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
sys
tmp
usr
var
$ cat stderr.log 
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the previous answer (and my comment), there is the attach of `docker run` from the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run `-a, --attach=[]            Attach to STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR`