# Make docker-compose logs -f only show /dev/stderr

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a container which runs Apache2 and has some log files that print their input into `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`. When running `docker-compose logs -f` it blindly prints both `stdout` and `stderr` mixed. Is there any way to only show one of the two?

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 10 01:22 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 10 01:22 error.log -> /dev/stderr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 10 01:22 other_vhosts_access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

Ideally, I'd like to optionally switch between outputs. I could imagine `--only-stderr` and `--only-stdout` flags. I'm aware of possible workarounds for this, but I'm interested if this is natively possible.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910885/python-exceptions-in-docker-logs-marked-as-stream-stdout/30911901#30911901 for some ideas on how to do this with just docker (not docker-compose)

Comment: You can remove the symlink for access log and leave the logs inside the container if you want or mount it using a volume

Comment: I just edited my original question to be a bit more clear what I want to achieve: filtering the `docker-compose logs -f` based on what I'd like to see. Essentially giving me the power to choose which output is printed from `docker-compose logs`. Edit: Might be out of scope for `logs`, though I was wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I see your point and I would need the same thing, but apparently it's not supported by docker-compose at the moment.

See this feature request: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6078

---

Although you cannot do that with docker-compose, you can still achieve something similar by following the logs of a particular Docker container.

> You wrote "I'm aware of possible workarounds for this" so you might know it already, but it will hopefully help other people visiting this page :)

After executing `docker-compose up`, list your running containers:

```
docker ps
```

Copy the NAME of the given container and read its logs:

```
docker logs NAME_OF_THE_CONTAINER -f
```

To only read the **error logs**:

```
docker logs NAME_OF_THE_CONTAINER -f 1>/dev/null
```

To only read the **access logs**:

```
docker logs NAME_OF_THE_CONTAINER -f 2>/dev/null
```